# When an edit is suggested on a post, is there a delay before it joins the peer review queue?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I have been reading [about how suggested edits work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work/76284#76284), and in my mind, it leaves one thing unanswered.

Let's say I post an answer to a question. If somebody with less than 2k rep then suggests an edit, what happens exactly?

- I know that I receive a notification about the edit, whereby I can approve or reject it.
- I know that suggested edits appear in the suggested edits peer review queue.
- I also know that, as the original author of the post, I get the final/overriding say in whether the suggested edit is approved or rejected, regardless of the result from the peer review queue.

Specifically, I am wondering whether the original author of the post (i.e. in this case, me) receives a grace period in which to approve or reject the edit *before* it appears in the aforementioned queue?  If so, what are the details about this delay please?  Does it make any difference whether the author has been recently active on SO?

I think it would be a good idea to avoid potentially wasting reviewers time if the OP is online to immediately approve or reject the changes.

Comment: No grace period as far as I know.  Putting such a delay on suggested edits can jam up other suggestions, so getting them through review quickly is preferable.

Comment: Of course there is.  It takes SO 6 to 8 units of time to do anything ;)

Comment: I guess that there is a delay before it will be peer reviewed, in the sense that, it is however long it takes for all the existing items in the queue to be reviewed first ;)

Comment: "I also know that, as the original author of the post, I get the final/overriding say in whether the suggested edit is approved or rejected, regardless of the result from the peer review queue." - I really wish it were that way! (I have seen that @Magisch has already addressed that in her answer). It would be great to know why an OP doesn't have veto power in such a case.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I know that I receive a notification about the edit, whereby I can
>   approve or reject it.

Thats correct. This happens immediately.

> I know that suggested edits appear in the suggested edits peer review
>   queue.

Thats also correct. This also happens immediately.

Depending on how many suggested edits are queued for review and how many people are reviewing them currently, the review can be completed in a minute or less, or take an hour or more on here.

> I also know that, as the original author of the post, I get the
>   final/overriding say in whether the suggested edit is approved or
>   rejected, regardless of the result from the peer review queue.

Thats only partially correct. When the review task is completed before you see it (by x3 approve, x3 reject, x1 reject and edit or x1 improve edit), then you don't have the ability to retroactively change the review outcome.

You can however roll the edit back (any user above 2k or the owner of the post can do that) and then apply your own.